# Prolog Code - No idea what it does

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I was wondering what this code does:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options,
  [quoted(true), portray(true), attributes(portray), max_depth(100)]).
```

I have seen it in some of the sample codes my prof has posted on his website but I have no clue what it does. Thanks for  your help in advance.

Comment: have you considered asking your prof?

Comment: I thought I will get a quicker answer here. Is there a problem with posting stuff like this?

Comment: Well, prolog is not the most widely used language. And asking the person who wrote something is likely to get an answer. Plus, what do you think it does? What research have you done?

Comment: I'm aware of that, thank you. I have gone through the notes and Googled it and I'm currently trying to see if I can find something about it in my textbook.

Comment: the SWI-Prolog docs are inline [here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272.11%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/flags.html%27%29%29)

Comment: I also don't really get the point of smartass comments like that. If you don't know the answer, you can move on. No one's forcing you to give an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it might have something to do with making program output more formatted (and thus, more readable or accessible.)

See this article: *["Help... Prolog writes [x, y, z|...], I want the whole answer"](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html)*.

Basically, in the case of your code's settings... it looks like the code is just setting some formatting for output.  The `max_depth` setting means that anything that is nested more than (100, in your case,) levels will then be written as `...`.  The rest of the options just enable normal output.